# Solaris 11 remove the old "entire"

Tags: solaris, ips

```
pkg list -af entire
NAME (PUBLISHER)                                  VERSION                    IFO
entire                                            0.5.11-0.175.2.11.0.5.0    i--
entire                                            0.5.11-0.175.2.10.0.5.0    ---
entire                                            0.5.11-0.175.2.9.0.5.0     ---
entire                                            0.5.11-0.175.2.8.0.4.0     ---
entire                                            0.5.11-0.175.2.7.0.4.0     ---
entire                                            0.5.11-0.175.2.0.0.42.0    ---
```

Those "entires" are old, except, of course, the first,is it possible to remove them with the `pkg` command?

Comment: Only the one with "i" in the IFO column is installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not all installed.  To "remove" them, don't use the `-af` flag to `pkg list`.

From the [Solaris pkg man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E21796/pkg-1.html):

> ...
>
> list [-Hafnsuv] [-g path_or_uri ...] [--no-refresh] [pkg_fmri_pattern ...]
>
> ...
>
> With -f and -a, list all versions of all packages for all variants
>   regardless of incorporation constraints or installed state. ...

Because you're using the `-af` flags, you're seeing every version available from any of your publishers.